# How do I connect to my database in cloud 9?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, cloud9-ide

So I set up the database and a table within it, but I'm continuously getting the same error.

[HERE'S the error](http://puu.sh/cn36h/fd39c8c71c.png)

Is there any way to check if I made a password for this? I know that the default is to leave it blank so I'm not sure if maybe I made one in the past or not.

PHP CODE

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Database</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('0.0.0.0', 'anthonyrodriguez726', '', 'dbtest' );

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die(
        "Database connection failed:" . mysqli_connect_error() . "(" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
        );
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Connecting to your database through cloud makes no difference if you have an FTP project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have inited the database. Use `mysql-ctl init` to do so.